# Make folder writable by multiple users via ACL

Tags: permissions, filesystems, access-control-list, user-permissions

Is it possible to set the rights of a folder and all its files in such a way that multiple defined users can add, modify and remove files within? I was hoping to be able to do that via ACLs and I got it working that multiple users can change files, but only the owner is able to delete those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deletion (and creation) of a file (name) modifies the containing directory, so the users need to have permission to write that directory.
Also note that in UNIX the rights do not inherit normally (see also `set-group-ID` in `inode(7)`).

See these Superuser questions:

[Linux - group member cannot delete file with rw permission](https://superuser.com/questions/784952/linux-group-member-cannot-delete-file-with-rw-permission)

[Why can't I delete a file where I have group write permissions on?](https://superuser.com/questions/373115/why-cant-i-delete-a-file-where-i-have-group-write-permissions-on)